# Video: Who crossed the finishline first?

Tags: video-processing, shape-analysis

Okey, so there was a boat race during the weekend. It was a very tight race, but a few minutes after the race, the green boat was declared winner.

Given only this video images, how can they determine this?
http://kvf.fo/kapprodur?sid=70276
Crossing finish line around 5:17
(Download best quality press "Tak niður" -> "Hágóðska")

Iv tried with ffmpeg to fiddle around with colors but i have no luck to determine if in fact green or yellow won. In fact the colors seem to very distracting.

[image]

Any suggestion to how I can render a more determinable result?